# set Checkbox value from Datareader

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, sqldatareader

I am trying to pull information from a database into a form.

the database stores checkbox values as a single (-1 for true 0 for false)

However i am unable to set the .checked state of the checkbox with this.

```
frmTool.chkMeterFake.CheckState = dr("VALIDATE")
```

i have also tried

```
frmTool.chkMeterFake.CheckState = Convert.ToBoolean(dr("VALIDATE"))
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `bit` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Checked` property instead of `CheckState`:

```
frmTool.chkMeterFake.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(dr("VALIDATE"))
```

The `CheckState` property is useful when you want your checkbox to have three possible states: checked, unchecked, or not set.

Comment: Knew it would be something simple im overlooking. This has worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a `bit` column for booleans?

However, you can use this:

```
Dim validateIndex = dr.GetOrdinal("Validate")
frmTool.chkMeterFake.Checked = dr.GetFloat(validateIndex) = 0
```

Comment: I did not build the database. I'm just counting myself lucky its not a string.